# Problema al recargar pagina y mantener el contenido

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo el siguiente problema: 
hace un tiempo adapte un script jQuery para un menú que cambia el interior de una página ocultando y mostrando el contenido según el link que se presione, el contenido esta en una sola página y no se como hacer para que al recargar la web se mantenga en el contenido que indica el link

aca el codigo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ultimo=1;
 $('#menu-sup li a').click(function(){
  // obtenemos el nuevo id
  nuevo=$(this).parent().attr("id");
  if(nuevo!=ultimo){
   // escondemos el ultimo id
   $("#cont"+ultimo).fadeOut(function(){
   $("#"+ultimo).removeClass("select");
   $("#"+nuevo).addClass("select");
   // mostramos el nuevo id
   $("#cont"+nuevo).fadeIn();
   ultimo=nuevo;
   });
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.cont{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seccion-p">
<div class="menu">
 <ul id="menu-sup">
  <li id="1" class="select "><a href="#inicio">Inicio</a> </li>
  <li id="2" ><a href="#Admisiones">Admisiones</a></li>
  <li id="3" ><a href="#Usuarios">Usuarios</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="contenido-menu">
 <div id="cont1">contenido 1</div>
 <div id="cont2" class="cont">contenido 2</div>
 <div id="cont3" class="cont">contenido 3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Editado.
Encontré una manera no muy elegante de hacerlo, el script del click lo deje como función ckick_menu() luego obteniendo el hash y asignandolo a una variable que contiene el link del menú 'm_click' después repito el mismo código de la función click para luego hacer un trigger del click lo que permite que se cargue el contenido al recargar el sitio y finalmente llamo a la función click_menu() con el parámetro 'm_click' redefinido. Esto funciona no al 100% ya que si carga el contenido pero al hacer click en el otro menú no oculta la información que se recargó. Gracias por las respuestas :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   function click_menu(menu_click){
  var ultimo=1;
  $(menu_click).click(function(){
     // obtenemos el nuevo id
     nuevo=$(this).parent().attr("id");
     if(nuevo!=ultimo){
       //ultimo = ultimo+1;// escondemos el ultimo id
    $("#cont"+ultimo).fadeOut(function(){
       $("#"+ultimo).removeClass("select");
       $("#"+nuevo).addClass("select");
       // mostramos el nuevo id
       $("#cont"+nuevo).fadeIn();
       ultimo=nuevo; 
       });
     }
  });
   }
hash = '[href="'+document.location.hash+'"]';
   if(hash){
  menu_click = '#menu-sup li a'+hash+'';
  $(menu_click).click(function(){
  var ultimo=1;
  // obtenemos el nuevo id
  nuevo=$(this).parent().attr("id");
  if(nuevo!=ultimo){
 // escondemos el ultimo id
 $("#cont"+ultimo).fadeOut(function(){
       $("#"+ultimo).removeClass("select");
    $("#"+nuevo).addClass("select");
    // mostramos el nuevo id
    $("#cont"+nuevo).fadeIn();
    ultimo=nuevo;
    });
  }
});
$(menu_click).trigger('click',);
menu_click = '#menu-sup li a';
click_menu(menu_click);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con el paso de varaibles de Session desde php a js o con variables de navegador que no se eliminan ni cerrando el navegador ejmplo asi:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ultimo=1;
  //preguntas si la variable existe en el navegador
  if(localStorage.getItem("ultimo")!=null){
    //sino existe la crea
    localStorage.setItem("ultimo", ultimo);
  }else{
    //si ya existe, entonces le asignas su valor a la variable
    //manipulas normal el codigo
    ultimo = localStorage.getItem("ultimo");
    $('#menu-sup li a').click(function(){
      // obtenemos el nuevo id
      nuevo=$(this).parent().attr("id");
      if(nuevo!=ultimo){
        // escondemos el ultimo id
        $("#cont"+ultimo).fadeOut(function(){
        $("#"+ultimo).removeClass("select");
        $("#"+nuevo).addClass("select");
        // mostramos el nuevo id
        $("#cont"+nuevo).fadeIn();
        //y por ultimo le asignas el nuevo valor a la variable
        localStorage.setItem("ultimo", nuevo);
        });
      }
    });

  }
});
```

espero te sirva, me cuentas!

Comment: hola, Probé la recomendación pero no funcionó queda en el mismo lugar Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Muy simple, existe una propiedad `document.location.hash` que contiene el hash del url (#Etiqueta).

Solo tienes que añadir esta pequeña funcionalidad a tu página

```
if(document.location.hash) $('a[href="'+document.location.hash+'"]').addClass('select');
```

dentro de

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ...
});
```

Comment: hice los cambios pero queda igual al recargar el sitio, pero con el "hash" se me ocurrió otra manera no muy elegante